# C++ program to take 2 sentences and find common letters?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, character

i'm trying to write a program in c++ to find shared letters in 2 sentences entered by a user , the code i entered is below but for some reason it's not working , the function must return all of the shared letters between the two sentences. Thanks in advance!

```
        #include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int  findSharedLetters(const char line1[], const char line2[]);
void main()
{
    char line1[100] , line2[100];
    cout<<"Enter line 1 : ";
    cin.getline(line1 , 100);
    cout<<"Enter line 2 : ";
    cin.getline(line2 , 100);
    char result = findSharedLetters(line1,line2);
    cout<<"shared letters : "<<result<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
int  findSharedLetters(const char line1[], const char line2[])
{
for(int i = 0;i<line1[100];i++)
    {
    for(int x = 0;x<line2[100];x++)
        {
        if(line1[i] == line2[x])
        {
        return line1[i];
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This is not how it works, what happens when you execute your program, what are you expecting, why ? How many common letters do you want to get ? Do you always supply sentences of the same length ?

Comment: The sentences can have up to 100 characters , the user can have different length for each sentence and i'm trying to find all of the common letters between both sentences.

Comment: @KareemYoussef your program can only handle 99 chars sentences. Test your program with sort sentences: "a" and "a", or "a"/"b", then slightly longer: "ab"/"ab", "ab"/"ba", "aaabccc"/"dddaeee" ...

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is based on using classes `std::string` and `std::set`  and standard algorithm `std::set_intersection`

Here is a sample program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::set<char> FindSharedLetters( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    std::set<char> st1( s1.begin(), s1.end() );
    std::set<char> st2( s2.begin(), s2.end() );

    std::set<char> st0;

    std::set_intersection( st1.begin(), st1.end(), 
                           st2.begin(), st2.end(),
                           std::inserter( st0, st0.end() ) );

    return ( st0 );
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s1( "DCAB" );
    std::string s2( "FRDC" );

    for ( char c : FindSharedLetters( s1, s2 ) ) std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
C D
```

The solution is case-sensitive relative to letters.

The task is more compound if you need to find only common alpha characters independing on the case.

Here is how it can be done using the same containers and algorithm as above

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

std::set<char> FindSharedLetters( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    std::set<char> st1;
    std::set<char> st2;

    for ( char c : s1 )
    {
        if ( std::isalpha( c ) ) st1.emplace( std::toupper( c ) );
    }

    for ( char c : s2 )
    {
        if ( std::isalpha( c ) ) st2.emplace( std::toupper( c ) );
    }

    std::set<char> st0;

    std::set_intersection( st1.begin(), st1.end(), 
                           st2.begin(), st2.end(),
                           std::inserter( st0, st0.end() ) );

    return ( st0 );
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s1( "12dCAB$" );
    std::string s2( "#FRDc12" );

    for ( char c : FindSharedLetters( s1, s2 ) ) std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Again the output is

```
C D
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the function once you found a letter pair.
Store the the letters in a string and return that instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
std::string findSharedLetters(const char line1[], const char line2[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  char line1[100] , line2[100];
  line1[0] = '\0'; // make sure it's empty
  line2[0] = '\0'; // make sure it's empty

  cout<<"Enter line 1 : ";
  cin.getline(line1 , 100);
  cout<<"Enter line 2 : ";
  cin.getline(line2 , 100);
  std::string result = findSharedLetters(line1,line2); // function returns string now
  cout<<"shared letters : "<<result<<endl;
// removed system("pause"); as my compiler cried...
    return 0;
}
std::string findSharedLetters(const char line1[], const char line2[]){
  std::string returnLine = ("");
  for(int i = 0;i<(sizeof(line1)/sizeof(*line1));i++) // iterate through size of array
  {
    for(int x = 0;x<(sizeof(line2)/sizeof(*line2));x++) // iterate through size of array
    {
      if(line1[i] == line2[x])
        if (!(line1[i]=='\0')) { // if empty space detected, it skips
        returnLine += line1[i]; // add matching char to string
        }
    }
  }
  return returnLine; //return the string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! , can you please explain what you did inside the function as i can't seem to get how it works , also is there a way for it to be done without using the sizeof function?

Comment: You can replace the sizeOf functions with values instead. like
      **for(int i = 0;i<100;i++)**